# Providing Excel sheets and a connection string as inputs while Packaging a job in Talend

Tags: connection-string, user-input, packaging, talend

I have designed a job to copy Excel data to SQL tables (18 of them). Now I want to package it.
Since I am new to this I don't know how to proceed.

I want to package it in a way that user can provide Excel input sheets and a connection string. And my executable file will copy data from this 'n' number of input sheets to the hard-coded tables.
Now user might want to copy data from any number of tables.

My workflow is

```
Stored Procedure -> excel input -> tMap -> tMSSql
                          |
                    on sub job ok
                          |
                    excel input -> tMap -> tMSSql
                          |
                    on sub job ok
                          |
                       ......
                          |
                    excel input -> tMap -> tMSSql
```

I want to know where and how to define these as input parameters? Or whatever the other way it works in Talend.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use context variables that can then be defined at run time.

In this case you'll want one variable for the location and file name for the Excel sheet and potentially you'll also want to contextualise your DB connection parameters too.

If you have varying amounts of sheets per workbook you'll need to reconfigure your job to loop through the sheets in the workbook and output to the appropriate table rather than hard code the amount of sheets you work through. This can also be done with context variables but these should be controlled by your loop rather than defined at run time.

If you are using Talend Open Studio then you'll want to pass your runtime contexts as a parameter when starting the job in either command line or shell/batch script. With the Enterprise editions you can specify context variables in the Talend Administration Console.

To overwrite any set context variable values at run time you can pass this as a parameter to your job when running it from a batch or shell script by adding `--context_param [param-name]=[param-value]` such as `C:/Talend/Jobs/job.bat --context_param inputDir="C:/Talend/inputDir/"`

Comment: Right now I want to design it for fix number of sheets in a workbook.
Yes, I am using Talend Open Studio.
What do I need to change with my previous job and how do I provide context variables for Excel sheet (location + name) and DB connection?

Comment: You'll need to create context variables in the contexts part of Talend and then use them by calling them as `context.contextName` in the appropriate part of the component that needs them. So your Excel component should be looking for an input of something like `context.WorkbookPath` where your WorkbookPath context would be a full path to your workbook

Comment: Thanks, And what should be my approach for DB connection?

Comment: I have taken a context variable named WorkbookPath. And provided it's default value as 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Workbook1.xlsx' (with out the comma). 
So now all of my Excel inputs will have 'context.WorkbookPath' (with out the commas) written in it's 'File name/Stream' field?

And how do I provide my input the value to look for particular work sheet in that workbook?

Comment: You'll need to do a similar thing for your DB connection parameters (if your DB parameters are expected to change). As for specifying them at run time, I'm honestly not sure as I've never used the Open Studio but you should be able to Google it or ask another question about how to define context variables at run time.

Comment: The thing I tried for Excel sheet's location ain't working. It says "WorkbookPath can not be resolved or is not a field."
Actually I am not being able to find much related information from Google.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to define the values of the context variables at run time

Comment: I have used 7 context variables in my batch file. Rather than modifying batch file every time with complex syntax I wan to run that job with my own context variables values.
I would like to mention only the file name (i.e. job1) and context variables values.
So my file would contain text which is 'job1 a b c t x y z'.
where a b c t x y z are my context variables values. I expect job1 to run using these values. How do I modify my batch file for this?

Comment: For now my Job1_run (batch file from the exported folder) has.....
 
--context_param ExcelFileLocation=%1 --context_param Host=%2 --context_param Database=%3 --context_param Schema=%4  --context_param Username=%5 --context_param Password=%6 --context_param StoredProcedure=%7 %*

And my other batch file has..
Job1_run "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DemoData.xlsm" "localhost" "dbo" "Test" "Username" "Password" "StoredProcedureName"

But its not wroking. Kindly suggest the solutions.